# Python Self Avoiding Random Walk (Returns to the Origin)

Tags: python

I've been trying to implement a self avoiding random walk that returns to the origin when available. The problem is when I try to calculate the probability of happening.

**I'm considering a successful walk when it has returned to the origin(0, 0) and it has an Area>0 that means it has done steps >= 4**

- All libraries

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy as sc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
from scipy.special import  comb
```

- Function to generate the self avoiding random walk

```py
def generateMoves(x, y):
  return [(x + 1, y), (x - 1, y), (x, y + 1), (x, y - 1)]

def SARW(limit = 1): #generates the movement
  origin = (0, 0)
  positions = [] #stores all moves done
  positions.append(origin)
  x, y = [0], [0] #variables for generating moves

  stuck = 0 #variable to check whether it has stopped
  returned = 0 #checks if it has returned to the origin
  movements = 0 #steps count
  i = 0

  while True:#Loop for walk
    moves = generateMoves(x[-1], y[-1]) #generates the moves
    availables = [] #stores all possible walks available
    movements += 1 #increments the steps count
    for mx, my in moves: #loop for checking the available movements
      if (mx, my) not in positions: #if x and y is not in positions then we add to availables
        if (-limit <= mx <= limit) and (-limit <= my <= limit): #checks if the possible move is contain in the space between the limit e.g {-1; 1}
          availables.append((mx, my)) #it stores x and y in availables
      if (0, 0) in moves and movements > 0: #this lets the walk returned to the origin if it has already moved one step
        availables.append((0, 0)) #we store origin in availables
    if availables: #it checks if there are available steps for it to walk 
      mx, my = availables[np.random.choice(len(availables))] #it chooses a random value between the available options
      positions.append((mx, my)) #it updates our array for positions with our random choice
      x.append(mx) #it saves x and y values
      y.append(my) 
    else:
      stuck = 1 #stops the loop if it has stopped
      movements = i + 1 
      break

    if origin in positions[1:]: #it breaks the loop if it has returned to the origin
      returned = 1
      movements = i + 1
      break
    i += 1
  return x, y, stuck, movements, returned, positions #returns all Values
```

- Function to calculate the probability of success

```py
def prob_of_return(iterations = 10): #simulates the walks
  #variables
  allsteps = 0
  prob = 0
  count_success = 0  
  for i in range(0, iterations):
    x, y, stuck, movements, returned, positions = SARW(limit = 10) #calls our function to generate the random Walk
    if (returned == 1) and (movements >= 4): #increments our counter if it was a succesfull walk
      count_success += 1
    
  prob = count_success / iterations

  return count_success, prob
```

solving the problem analytically has gave me a probability of 0.5802
so that should be the expected output, instead I'm having a probability of **(0.3292)**

***graph of probability as the limits increases***

[image]

Comment: ... *if* your analytic solution is correct.  We have no way to check your solution -- or a public solution, if there is one (please provide a link).  Is it possible to partition that solution into sub-portions to check against the paths found in your code?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, and the problem was in the if statement when I let the walk return to the origin, here is how I solve it

```py
    for mx, my in moves: #loop for checking the movements available
      if (mx, my) not in positions: #if x and y is not in positions then we add to availables
        if (-limit <= mx <= limit) and (-limit <= my <= limit): #checks if the possible move is contain in the space between the limit e.g {-1; 1}
          availables.append((mx, my)) #it stores x and y in availables
      if (mx, my) == (0, 0):
        availables.append((mx, my))
```